# Trying to set datetime variable value as empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to attribute the value of `null` to a variable of type DateTime.

taken property in model class value as

```
public DateTime? ClosedOn = null;
```

While reading it at controller end, I am using the code below :

```
member.ClosedOn = reader[6].ToString().Equals(DBNull.Value)|| reader[6].ToString().Equals("") ? null: Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6].ToString());.
```

But I am getting the following error :

> "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
> no implicit conversion between `null` and DateTime

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `(DateTime?)null`.  Basically the conditional cannot determine the type without a bit of help.  Also you should be able to do `reader.IsDbNull(6)`

Comment: What does `reader[6]` return? If it's a string, there's no reason to use `ToString()` at all. If it's a datetime, there's no reason to use any code at all. Have you tried just casting this to `DateTime?`, eg `(DateTime?)reader[6]` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Assuming `reader` is a `DbDataReader` then it's an `object` that could be either `DateTime` or `DbNull` assuming the data type of that column is a date.

Comment: @juharr hence the question first, and the duplicate later. The accepted answer is simply wrong if the value is a date already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that the compiler can't determine the type from just `null`, but you can help it out by casting it to the type, using: `(DateTime?) null`:

```
member.ClosedOn = reader[6].ToString().Equals(DBNull.Value) || 
                  reader[6].ToString().Equals("") 
    ? (DateTime?) null
    : Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6].ToString());
```

Similarly, because `null` is the default value for a nullable type, you could also use: `default(DateTime?)` instead of `null`:

```
member.ClosedOn = reader[6].ToString().Equals(DBNull.Value) || 
                  reader[6].ToString().Equals("") 
    ? default(DateTime?)
    : Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6].ToString());
```

Comment: It's quite possible that `reader[6]` is already a `DateTime`

Comment: Even if it isn't comparing a string to `DBNull.Value` will always be false